# How to remove Vim from fedora?

Tags: vim

I wanted to install some Plugins on vim so I played around with some files and I think I did something horribly wrong since there are bugs everywhere when I try to do something with vim.
So I want to know if it is possible to COMPLETELY remove vim? 
I have already tried it with `yum remove`, but that didn't help me out (I think the files from vim have still been there).

Comment: What are “bugs everywhere”? Does `vim -u NONE` work?

Comment: If you configure vim and install plugins and such, that often means you have made changes *in your home directory*.  Possibly you need to remove your `.vim` folder.